# Limiting network activity on a server

Tags: networking, bandwidth

I have a network with couple of servers running Windows Server 2008 R2. I am being ask to find out a way to limit the network activity per actions. So far i couldn't find if it's even of the realm of possibility.

An example is that i am on specific server locally and i am doing a remote desktop to a second server. I decide to copy paste some files trough the remote desktop session and that cause the network card usage to hit 100% for couple minutes. What i need to find is how to limit this to not take more than X %.

Another situation, i have a server with an FTP and i want that any connection to not use more than X % of the network card maximum bandwidth.

And another situation, we have a IIS server that receives thousands of connections which i need to limit the speed of each and all those plusIIS is making calls to another Server with MSSQL on it which also take network bandwidth and i need to limit that as well.

I have issue as some server become unresponsive when the network card activity reach 100% utilization.

All network cards/router/switches are 1 gbps

Does the kind of limitation i am looking for even exist ? Is there a term for this kind of limitation (i am not an IT guy) ?

Most server specs are :

- 2 x Xeon E7-4850 2.1 ghz (16 cores each, 32 total)
- 48 to 64 gb ram
- large raids with dozens of disk

Comment: How do you know it is network activity causing the performance issue? I have to say, I can’t think of a single situation where a saturated 1Gbps connection caused any significant response issues for others. Yes, it may be slower, but not “unresponsive.” What is more likely happening is that you have a significant bottleneck with your server hardware and the network activity is just an indicator that the server is busy processing requests. I’ve made dozens of simultaneous, multi-gig transfers over low end equipment with no significant issues, other than slowing.

Comment: when copy pasting over remote desktop i reach 100% network utilization with 122-123 mb / seconds.

Comment: And if you add a second file transfer you will get half that speed for both simultaneously. You are saying, instead your servers are “unresponsive.” This is not a network bandwidth issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually handled by QoS or Quality of Service.

On the Windows server itself, you may need to look at the Server Process itself, for example, many ftp servers offer the ability to limit download / upload rate.

Other than that, you will need external device, that support Quality of Service, like a Cisco router, which can limit bandwidth per conversation.

Comment: Good idea, i didn't think of QOS. Will check with the Netgear equipement if i have such feature.